# Blazor The name 'Invoke' doesn exist in the current context

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, devexpress, blazor

I am using Visual Studio 2019 Preview 4, .NET Core 3 RC1,

I create a Blazor web-app (server blazor), I follow https://docs.devexpress.com/Blazor/DevExpress.Blazor.Base.DxTextBoxBase.TextChanged#remarks

```
<DxTextBox Text="" TextChanged=@((newValue) => OnTextChanged(newValue))></DxTextBox>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" disabled=@IsDisabled>Update Text</button>

@code {
    bool IsDisabled = true;

    void OnTextChanged(string newValue)
    {
        if (newValue != null)
            IsDisabled = false;

        Invoke(StateHasChanged);
    }
}
```

I catch error

> The name 'Invoke' doesn exist in the current context

[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You now need to call `InvokeAsync()` in its place.

This was changed in the [Preview 8 release, mentioned here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-and-blazor-updates-in-net-core-3-0-preview-8/). Check the breaking changes at the top of that blog post, as well as those in the [Preview 9 post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-and-blazor-updates-in-net-core-3-0-preview-9/), as you may encounter other errors from updating. There were no breaking changes from Preview 9 to RC1, and will likely be no further changes for the 3.0 release in 11 hours.

You change it to

```
<DxTextBox Text="" TextChanged=@((newValue) => OnTextChanged(newValue))></DxTextBox>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" disabled=@IsDisabled>Update Text</button>

@code {
    bool IsDisabled = true;

    void OnTextChanged(string newValue)
    {
        if (newValue != null)
            IsDisabled = false;

        InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you think you should `await` InvokeAsync ?

Comment: The code was added via edit by the guy who asked the question, so I guess that's what he ended up using. If you change it to `async Task OnTextChanged(string newValue)` then you can await it. I haven't tried it like this, but you could potentially change the first line to use `TextChanged=@(async (newValue) => await OnTextChanged(newValue))` although I'm not sure how necessary that is in Blazor